# Get Data to connect to the AdventureWorksDW

Tags: sql-server-2017, visual-studio-2017, azure-analysis-services

I am trying to connect to a SQL Server 2017 via Visual Studio 2017.What should I be entering in the User name and Password fields?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, *databases* don't have passwords.  SQL Server uses logins, via either Windows Authentication or SQL Server Authentication.

Try using the same login you use to sign on to your workstation.